# How to separate loader with message

Tags: jquery, css, animation, loader

I am trying to separate message with loader, message is displaying under the loader which is not right I want the loader to separate or somewhere right side of the message:

My jQuery function:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
  url: url,
  beforeSend: function (){
    var html = "<div class=\"messages warning\">\n" +
      "<h2>Network Drive Sync In process</h2>\n" +
      "Please do not close or refresh this window during process</blockquote></div>"
    jQuery("#block-system-main").html(html);

  },
```

My Css file for loader:

```
.messages-warning {
border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
border-radius: 50%;
border-top: 16px solid blue;
border-bottom: 16px solid blue;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
-webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
 }

  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }

 @keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

I have also attached the screen shot of output currently I am having:

[image]

You can see in picture message is displaying with the loader, how I can separate loader from message so it should be at left side of message.

Comment: You can post html code to see how is structured

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're animating the entire container. To me, your intent seems to be to create a spinner and animate that, while having static text appear near the loader. To accomplish that most simply, you can:

Change this:

```
var html = "<div class=\"messages warning\">\n" +
      "<h2>Network Drive Sync In process</h2>\n" +
      "Please do not close or refresh this window during process</blockquote></div>"
    jQuery("#block-system-main").html(html);
```

to

```
var html = "<div class=\"messages-container\"><div class=\"messages-warning\"></div>\n" +
      "<h2>Network Drive Sync In process</h2>\n" +
      "<blockquote>Please do not close or refresh this window during process</blockquote></div>"
    jQuery("#block-system-main").html(html);
```

Your text may not be positioned where you want, in which case I'd suggest wrapping the `h2` and `blockquote` with another `div`, adding CSS `width` to `messages-container`, and `float: left` to both `messages-warning` and the new `div` you just added. That could look like this:

```
<div class="messages-container">
  <div class="messages-warning"></div>
  <div class="messages-text">
    <h2>Network Drive Sync In process</h2>
    <blockquote>Please do not close or refresh this window during process</blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.messages-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.messages-warning, .messages-text {
  float: left;
}
```